# "Unfortunately game has stopped" error on Android device

Tags: unity, android, debugging

In Unity 2018.4.3f1, I am able to build my APK successfully, but when I try to launch it on my mobile device, it shows: "Unfortunately game has stopped".

I don't know the problem is. Here are the project settings I'm using:

[image: Rendering Settings inspector]

[image: Scripting Settings inspector]

Comment: You should be debugging for any errors thrown in the logcat of Android Studio or any similar IDE. The answer by Justin might work, but it is very generic. If you provide crash log details, people may be able to help better solve your problem.

Comment: When your game crashes, it should save a crash log that you can inspect for hints as to what caused the crash. Have you checked for leads like this? What did you find?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your project open the Plugins folder and open the Android folder.

Open up the android manifest and remove any lines written in the manifest that you are not using such as facebook sdk or another plugin you no longer use ect..

Save it / Rebuild and it should open up fine after that.

**-*edited to improve answer* -**

if the apk builds fine with no 'logcat or build player errors' and then you have issues after deployment.

The game instantly crashes before you even see the splash screen.

Normally these types of errors occur during the initialization of the android manifest file. 
Most likely due to something that was included within it that you are no longer using such as the 'facebook sdk' or another 'plugin' that has been deleted from the project but is still referenced inside the manifest file or something else along those lines.

After removing those from the file it will no longer hang and should boot up normally.

Comment: thank u it's working now i delete admob plugin

Comment: Glad to be of help, I improved the answer to better explain why that happens

Comment: the problem is that i use admob plugin , after i want to delete it but i didn't delete all package , now it's okey and thank you